# How to subset dataframe on factor levels when NA are present

Tags: r, subset, na

I'd like to subset a dataframe on factor levels but struggle to do so when `NA`s are present. Here are two comparative dataframes, one without `NA` in the factor column, one with `NA`:

```
df1 <- data.frame(v = c("ABC", "def", "ABC", "ghi"), 
                  f = c(4.11, 3.22, NA, 7.44))

df2 <- data.frame(v = c(NA, "ABC", "def", "ABC", "ghi"), 
                  f = c(2.33, 4.11, 3.22, NA, 7.44))
```

In `df1`, subsetting on factor levels works nicely. For example:

```
df1[!df1$v == "ABC",]
    v    f
2 def 3.22
4 ghi 7.44
```

By contrast, subsetting in `df2` is fraught with problems:

```
df2[!df2$v == "ABC",]
      v    f
NA <NA>   NA
3   def 3.22
5   ghi 7.44
```

The problems are twofold: (i) the row with `<NA>` in `df2$v` is included whereas it shouldn't and (ii) the value next to it (i.e. the value on the same row under `df2$f`) is `NA` whereas that value should be `2.33`.

How can I subset `df2` cleanly and correctly, so that the outcome is this:

```
      v    f
3   def 3.22
5   ghi 7.44
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the following line of code

```
df2[!(df2$v == "ABC") & !is.na(df2$v), ]

#     v    f
# 3 def 3.22
# 5 ghi 7.44
```

or also this line, which I prefer as I don't have to type a couple of extra parentheses

```
df2[df2$v != "ABC" & !is.na(df2$v), ]

#     v    f
# 3 def 3.22
# 5 ghi 7.44
```